# How do I generate &quot in XML from C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextwriter

I'm using XmlTextWriter to generate XML from a C# app. The initial input will be in this format, 1" , but I can replace it with whatever. I need to end up with `1&quot;` but I keep getting `1&amp;quot;`

C#

```
    xml.WriteStartElement("data");
    xml.WriteAttributeString("type", "wstring");
    xml.WriteString("1&quot;");
    xml.WriteEndElement();
```

Ha! When I past the XML I need in here it converts it to 1". But whats I really need to show is the actual `1&quot;` in the 3rd line of the code.

I also need to use / and Ø. How can I do this, thanks.

Comment: What does `xml.WriteString("1\"")` result in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to end up with 1" but I keep getting 1&quot;

That's because you're trying to do the XML API's job for it.

Your job is to provide just text - its job is to handle escaping and anything else XML needs to do.

So you should just use

```
xml.WriteString("1\"");
```

... where the backslash is just for the sake of C#'s string literal handling, and has nothing to do with XML. The logical value you're trying to write out is a 1 followed by a double-quote. Whether it's escaped as `&quot;` or not should be irrelevant to anything processing it. If you've got something which is over-sensitive, you should fix *that*.

If you *desperately* need this (and I would again strongly urge you not to), try:

```
xml.WriteString("1");
xml.WriteEntityRef("quot");
```

(I'd also urge you to use LINQ to XML unless you're in a situation where you *really* need to use `XmlWriter`. It'll make your life significantly simpler.)

Comment: The answer gives me 1", i need to end up with '1&quot;'. The XML is being used as a search. I'm trying to reproduce the output.

Comment: @topofsteel: They're equivalent in XML, other than situations where the escaping is *required* (which it isn't in a text node). Anything processing the XML should treat it th same way.

Comment: @topofsteel: See my edit for more details and an alternative, but please consider the alternatives.